# same hash multiple images

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Well, I want to create only one hash for multiple files i upload so all those files will have the same hash so i can load all of them at once using that hash, but the problem is that in the store function hash changes for every file and i want it to stay the same for that upload

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $picture = '';
    $hash = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 8);

    if ($request->hasFile('images'))
    {
        $files = $request->file('images');
        foreach($files as $file) {

            $image = new Upload();

            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $picture = date('His') .'.'. $extension;
            $destinationPath = base_path() . '/public/storage';
            $file->move($destinationPath, $picture);

            $image->hash = $hash;
            $image->file_name = $picture;
            $image->path = '/storage/'.$picture;
            $image->save($request->all());

            return redirect('/a/'.$hash);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate hash and place it in upload form hidden field. After upload just read $_POST['hash'] instead of generating it in store().